# Trigger a draw only once for any event handler

Tags: javascript

I have a rather complex JavaScript single-page application that has a main canvas that needs to be redrawn in response to various inputs by the user. Lots of events are being registered into various DOM elements and every such event has the potential to trigger a `draw()`. Currently, I just perform the `draw()` whenever there's a condition that needs to trigger it but that more often than not causes several `draw()` calls to occur in quick succession for from the same event.

Is there some pattern or mechanism I can use to deal with that?
Ideally I want the triggering condition to just set a flag and the draw to happen at the end of the event handling if the flag was set. Doing this manually though would require modifying dozens of registered events

Comment: This seems pretty broad. Can you show a [mcve] of what you mean? Are you looking for debouncing? Are you using any frameworks or libraries, or is this all vanilla?

Comment: If the issue is that the same event requiring only one draw() call is being invoked multiple times, could you test/set a variable in the draw() function at commencement, such as `drawing`, and set it to false when the function completes, such that if drawing is true return, otherwise set to true and perform the function?  This way subesquent calls in close proximity to the intitial triggering one will not be performed unless draw has already completed. If that is too simple, perhaps you could also test the event object's target or currentTarget to ensure the same element triggered the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern like this should do the trick I think.

```
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListenerRunOnce = function(name, callback) {
    const eventWrapper = (event) => {
        this.removeEventListener(name, eventWrapper);
        callback(event);
    };

    this.addEventListener(name, eventWrapper);
};
```

Comment: This is very interesting, but is it not inefficient for the browser to remove and register event listeners each time an event is triggered?